# How to setup DNS server in Server Manager on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, dns, iis

I want to setup DNS server because I am trying to host a website using IIS on Windows 10.

When I start Server Manager, it doesn't have anything because its Windows 10 and nothing is setup, which is expected. But how do I setup a DNS server?

If you see the screenshot, I don't know what to do there, I can't even enter anything to add to this list.

[image]

If I select *Manager* > *Add Roles and Features* as indicated in answer by Sunny, I get this dialog and can't move forward.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the Hyper-v is enabled on Windows 10 and you have created a virtual machine via Hyper-v. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Please move to right side of server manager and click Manage->Add Roles and Features.
In Add roles and Features Wizard, select Next->Next->Next->then select DNS Serever in Server Roles, and then following the guideline of the Wizard to complete the server role installation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks but I get a message when I do that, I have updated the question and attached screenshot.